# Using Field Calculator to split names but want to start count from right?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

Just learning python on my own as I'm working. I have a column of street names where some are two words or three words, so counting spaces from the left to the right is outputting incorrectly for me. I only need to know what the very last word in the line is of data in my column, e.g., Forest Acres Circle, Main St, Bracker Road West. I  tried using STREETNAME!.split(" ",2)[-1]  but with the count of words it is not outputting the correct information.

Comment: just a tip: you should try using the address library and it's AddressParser module. It will parse the street type, return a list and remove any guesswork about which word means what.

Comment: New to Arc and learning as I go, can you recommend a place to ready up on the Address Parser module and Address library

Comment: I would recommend downloading pycharm IDE. It  has a newbie friendly interface for installing libraries. Thats how I got address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as all your fields are space delimited, you can use this to split out your last word:

> > > a.split(" ")[-1].strip()

In your example, Forest Acres Circle would return "Circle"